# I want to extract a substring from mongo db field and check if it's divisible by 4

Tags: mongodb

I want to extract a substring from `mongo db` field and check if it's divisible by 4.

I have some a document like below:

```
{ 
   "form" : "form-1002",
   "requestType" : "POST"
},
{ 
   "form" : "form-1003",
   "requestType" : "POST"
}
```

I want to extract the documents on the basis of form field like `form-1002`, the 1002 is divisible by 2. and then update the request type based on query results. How can i achieve this?

Comment: By this you can get number and then do you logic accordingly whether it is divisible 4 or what number you want

`db.YOUR_COLLECTION.find({}).forEach( function(x) { print( x.form.split('-')[1] ); } );`

Comment: Your method works :)

Comment: Though i need to learn javascript i think

Answer (score 0):

**Using MongoDB 4.0 and newer:**

Construct an aggregate pipeline that makes use of the **[`$substrCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrCP/)** to return the substring of the form field with the numerical part.

Once you get the substring, convert it to a numerical value using **[`$toInt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/)** or **[`$convert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#exp._S_convert)**.

Use the **[`$mod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/)** operator to get the remainder when dividing the result from the previous operation by 2.

Following is an example that shows the full pipeline with different fields that show how each of the above operator operates:

```
const pipeline = [
    { "$addFields": {
        "formValue": {
            "$toInt": {
                "$substrCP": [
                    "$form",
                    5,
                    99999999
                ]
            }
        },
        "remainder": {
            "$mod": [
                {
                    "$toInt": {
                        "$substrCP": [
                            "$form",
                            5,
                            99999999
                        ]
                    }
                },
                2
            ]
        },
        "computedRequestType": {
            "$cond": [
                {
                "$eq": [
                        {
                            "$mod": [
                                {
                                    "$toInt": {
                                        "$substrCP": [
                                            "$form",
                                            5,
                                            99999999
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                2
                            ]
                        },
                        0
                ] 
                },
                "POST",
                "GET"
            ]
        }
    } }
]
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

And for those two documents the above yields:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b979ad11f21b55f5a1399c6"),
    "form" : "form-1002",
    "requestType" : "POST",
    "formValue" : 1002,
    "remainder" : 0,
    "computedRequestType" : "POST"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b979ad11f21b55f5a1399c7"),
    "form" : "form-1003",
    "requestType" : "POST",
    "formValue" : 1003,
    "remainder" : 1,
    "computedRequestType" : "GET"
}
```

---

To update the collection you may need to add another pipeline which uses the **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)** operator on the same collection but the pipeline would be as:

```
const pipeline = [
    { "$addFields": {
        "requestType": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [
                    { "$mod": [
                        { "$toInt": {
                            "$substrCP": [
                                "$form",
                                5,
                                99999999
                            ]
                        } },
                        2
                    ] },
                    0
                ] },
                "POST",
                "GET"
            ]
        }
    } },
    { "$out": "collection" }
]
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```